# Orca - Cannot save configuration

Tags: python, configuration, orca

I'm trying to change the voice person on the orca setup (orca -s) and when I try to click the buttons 'Apply' or 'OK' this error shows up in the console:

```
Gtk-Message: 12:48:35.589: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/orca/orca_gui_prefs.py", line 3054, in applyButtonClicked
    self.writeUserPreferences()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/orca/orca_gui_prefs.py", line 385, in writeUserPreferences
    keyBindingsDict)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/orca/settings_manager.py", line 485, in saveSettings
    self.profileKeybindings)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/orca/backends/gsettings_backend.py", line 232, in saveProfileSettings
    self._saveVoiceSettings(general['voices'], profile)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/orca/backends/gsettings_backend.py", line 615, in _saveVoiceSettings
    elif appSpecific == False and setEstablished == True:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'setEstablished' referenced before assignment
```

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS desktop.

Any idea what the problem might be or where can I find the configuration file to modify it manually??

Thanks,
Julián

Comment: Having the same problem with Ubuntu mate 19, but this suggested fix broke `orca`. I got speech back by `sudo apt remove -y orca`, then `sudo apt install -y orca`, then press alt+super+f2, but still can't save configuration changes to voice tab or keybindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem is in the file:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/orca/gsettings_backend.py
```

I managed to get around this in Ubuntu 19.10
moving the file to a hidden file!

```
sudo su
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/orca/
mv gsettings_backend.py .gsettings_backend.py
exit
reboot
```

After the system came back I was able to change the settings!

Comment: The file path seems different for Ubuntu 18. It is under `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/orca/backends`.